# Words that mean ''to say something unintentional''

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

I am looking for words that mean ''to say something unintentionally''

Comment: [*put your foot in your mouth*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/put-your-foot-in-your-mouth)

Comment: As in “blurt out” or “spill the beans” or “let slip” or as jxh asks, “put your foot in your mouth”?

Comment: @Jim does blurt also mean to talk without being aware of what you are saying?

Comment: It means to suddenly say something, on impulse,  before thinking about whether you *should* say it.  And it is usually only used when, in retrospect, you shouldn't have said it.

Comment: @Jim but blurt still means to say something unintentional?

Comment: Define *unintentional*

Comment: @Jim well what words mean that you don't realize what you are saying?

Comment: If you mean, for instance, suppose you got into a small accident where you bumped into a girl's car with your car.  Then later you and your friend are out and he sees a girl and says, "Wow she's cute." And you say, "That's the girl I banged last night" (meaning you banged into her with your car) not realizing that bang is also a euphemism. Then that would be saying something unintentionally but it would not be blurting out.

Comment: @Jim stop confusing me you answered before that  ''to blurt out'' means to say something unintentionally now you're saying it means not to say something unintentionally

Comment: Suppose your wife just told you she was pregnant but was keeping it a secret. Suppose you are out at dinner with her and her family and her Dad hands her a drink and she starts to drink it. You see this and blurt out, "No! Remember you're pregnant!" as all of her family turns to stare at you.  *That's blurting out* You didn't intend to tell everyone she was pregnant.  But you spoke before thinking about the consequences and implications.  That's different than saying something with a meaning you didn't intend.  But they both amount to saying something unintentionally.

Comment: @Jim What other cases is blurt used for than the case of secrets?

Comment: You can also have a blurt of laughter.

Answer (score 1):

To **blurt** or **blurt out**.

from [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blurt):

> *blurt* [Verb]:
>
> To utter suddenly and unadvisedly; to speak quickly or without
>   thought; to divulge inconsiderately — commonly with out.
>
> - *Please think about your reply and don't just blurt out the first thing that comes to mind*.

Further to comments to the OP:

- to "put your foot in your mouth" is to say something *embarrassing*, and
- to "spill the beans" is to *tell the facts* about something (presumably intentionally).
- To let something slip is to unintentionally reveal a fact which you should have kept secret — is this the meaning you wanted?

Comment: please explain more about ''blurt'' and ''blurt out''

Comment: why do they mean to say something unintentionally?

Comment: Hello? Will you please reply?

Comment: I think Jim has explained "blurt" well in his comments to your OP. I don't have anything more to add on the subject.

Comment: I like to hear your own explanation please